# Regex positive look-ahead not preventing a match

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

If [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/en0zfy/2/):

```
^(?:(?:\([^\(\)]+\))|(?:(?<!\()[^\(\)]+(?!\))))$
```

matches `abc` and `(abc)` but not `(abc` or `abc)`, why can't I use it in a positive look-ahead [like this](https://regex101.com/r/zE6tT7/1)?

```
^(?=(?:(?:\([^\(\)]+\))|(?:(?<!\()[^\(\)]+(?!\)))))(?:\(?[a-z]+\)?)$
```

It matches `abc)` for example.

Comment: Your first regex can be reduced to `^(?:\([^()]+\)|[^()]+)$`. When you used it in the lookahead, you did not anchor it at the end, you did not use `$`. The second regex you need is just `^(?:\([a-z]+\)|[a-z]+)$`. In .NET, you may also use `^(\()?[a-z]+(?(1)\))$`, see [**demo**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5c%28%29%3f%5ba-z%5d%2b%28%3f%281%29%5c%29%29%5cr%3f%24&i=abc%0d%0a%28anbv%29%0d%0ajh%29%0d%0a%28nj&o=m).

Comment: What are the rules which you are trying to follow? My best guess is that you want `a-z` without parentheses, with an opening or closing parenthesis, or with both parentheses.

Comment: Wow, tricky @WiktorStribiżew.  Thanks, I was going crazy.  And thanks for the reductions.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  yes to boil it down, I want to have characters enclosed in parens or not enclosed in parens.  I'm trying to prevent open but no close and vice versa.  I'm going to use this look-around for a number of different sets of characters optionally enclosed in parens.

Comment: So is `()` valid? What about `a(b)c`, `a)b(c`, `)(`, or `(ab(c)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first regex can be reduced to `^(?:\([^()]+\)|[^()]+)$`. When you used it in the lookahead, you did not anchor it at the end, you did not use `$`. So, the direct "quick fix" would look like

```
^(?=(?:\([^()]+\)|[^()]+)$)\(?[a-z]+\)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mjrrXE/1).

The second regex can also be written as mere `^(?:\([a-z]+\)|[a-z]+)$`, with two alternatives that either matches a lowercase letter string inside parentheses or without them.

In .NET, you may also use

```
^(\()?[a-z]+(?(1)\))$
```

See [**demo**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5c%28%29%3f%5ba-z%5d%2b%28%3f%281%29%5c%29%29%5cr%3f%24&i=abc%0d%0a%28anbv%29%0d%0ajh%29%0d%0a%28nj&o=m).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(\()?` - an optional capturing group #1 matching a `(`
- `[a-z]+` - 1+ lowecase letters (`\p{Ll}+` matches any lowercase Unicode letters)
- `(?(1)\))` - a conditional construct: if Group 1 matched (if there was an open parenthesis) match `)`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Ugg, the problem I'm having with this is that the pattern I'm actually using isn't at the end of the string/line.  In my simplified example it is, but in reality I have a number of these groups strung together, so `(123) (45) (678)` matches but `(123 (45) (678)` shouldn't match.  I can't find any other way to get the look-ahead to preclude characters beyond its current match, i.e. it allows `123)`.

Comment: If you know of a way to enforce a pattern like I'm trying to do, I would greatly appreciate it.  I've been working on this all day.

Comment: P.S. I know your answer is perfect for the way my question is written; the problem is that I made my example too simple.  If this goes as planned, I will write a new question and you can answer that if you like, too.

Comment: @rory.ap Do you want to match a string with paired parentheses only? Try `^[^()]*(?>(?>(?<open>\()[^()]*)+(?>(?<-open>\))[^()]*)+)+(?(open)(?!))$`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5e%28%29%5cn%5d*%28%3f%3e%28%3f%3e%28%3f%3copen%3e%5c%28%29%5b%5e%28%29%5cn%5d*%29%2b%28%3f%3e%28%3f%3c-open%3e%5c%29%29%5b%5e%28%29%5cn%5d*%29%2b%29%2b%28%3f%28open%29%28%3f!%29%29%5cr%3f%24&i=%28123%29+%2845%29+%28678%29%0d%0a%28123+%2845%29+%28678%29&o=m).

Comment: Well they are pairs, whether there or not.  So "(123) (456)" yes; "123 456" yes; "123 (456)" yes; "9876 (123) 456" yes; "(123 456" no; "(123 (456)" no; "1212 444) 2 (42)" no.  This is just an example.  There can be more groups of values within parens (or not).

Comment: Or, if you have no nested parentheses, [`^(?>\([^()]*\)|[^()]+)*$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3e%5c%28%5b%5e%28%29%5cn%5d*%5c%29%7c%5b%5e%28%29%5cn%5d%2b%29*%5cr%3f%24&i=%28123%29+%2845%29+%28678%29%0d%0a%28123+%2845%29+%28678%29&o=m) will do.